Issue with Java SimpleDateFormat while converting ZONES
I had a method like
public String format(long epochTimeInMS, String timeZone) {
    Date d = new Date(epochTimeInMS);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    return formatter.format(date);
  }

It used to return "22:49 PDT" for the values 1715752155000L, "PST", which is the expected behaviour. I was using jdk 8. After upgrading to jdk 17 the method is returning "21:41 GMT-08:00". Can you please hep with this ?

Oh interesting, on Java 21 (Temurin 21.0.3-9.0) on Windows in the CEST timezone returns "22:49 PDT" for me. Try a newer version of 17, maybe it was a bug that has already been fixed. Or move to DateTimeFormatter and in general the java.time APIs, they tend to be a lot more consistent as they're the modern alternative to java.util.Date and SDF.

Your snippet is incorrect. date is not defined. I assume it is d.

In Java 17.0.11 (OpenJDK on Linux) it returns "22:49 GMT-07:00". I think if your default time zone has "daylight savings", it uses that (so in my case, here in the UK, it uses "GMT-07:00" but if you're in India, where there is no "daylight savings", it uses "GMT-08:00"). The whole legacy Date and SimpleDateFormat classes are very confusing and you'd be well advised to switch to the "modern" (i.e. modern as of more than 10 years ago) java.time.* classes.

Solution using the java.time package which is the recommend way.
What is interesting is that "PST" is not a valid timezone (was deprecated a long time ago) though DateTimeFormatter can emit it. Use a real time zone such as America/Los_Angeles. The output has "PDT" because of current daylight savings, which is also the same I'm getting from SimpleDateFormat.
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long epochTimeInMS = 1_715_752_155_000L;
  
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = 
        Instant
            .ofEpochMilli(epochTimeInMS)
            .atZone(
                ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")
            );
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm z");
    String formattedString = zonedDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter);
        
    System.out.println("ZonedDateTime: "+ formattedString);
  }
}

See this code run at Ideone.
ZonedDateTime: 22:49 PDT


which jdk version you are using ?

am still getting GMT-08:00 and issue is only for America/Los_Angeles . I tried "Asia/Kolkata" it's giving 11:11 IST

Java 17 Temurin OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.11+9 (build 17.0.11+9)
